# How to implement "hold and drag" gesture in flutter?

Tags: flutter, gesture

"hold and drag" - would be holding down with one finger and dragging horizontally (or vertically) with another.

GestureDetector would recognize it as Scale gesture. I want to differentiate between these 2:

- Two fingers moving closer or further apart (normal scale)
- **One finger holding and another finger moving closer or further** (I want to detect this)

Comment: You can use Draggable constructor to drag any item.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html

Answer (score 5):

There's  a built-in Widget for that called [LongPressDraggable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LongPressDraggable-class.html) you can use it similar to the [Draggable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html) widget.

The one main common difference being the ability to directly drag using the Draggable widget or hold and drag using the LongPressDraggable Widget.

Comment: Thanks, but what I was looking for is basically a scale gesture, but one finger doesn't move

Comment: You can always implement your custom gestures using the GestureDetector and if you are trying to have a scale gesture you can try onScaleStart and onScaleUpdate properties of [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/GestureDetector.html)